# Binding proxy for remote Object in java RMI

Tags: java, rmi, classcastexception, dynamic-proxy

I would implement a security layer for java RMI, with dynamic proxy mechanism.
I've some class with remote interface that bind in rmi registry, now I'm coding a class SecurityInvocationHandler, code below:

```
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.rmi.server.RMIClientSocketFactory;
    import java.rmi.server.RMIServerSocketFactory;

    /** 
    *
    * @author andrew
    * @param <T>
    */
    public class SecurityInvocationHandler<T> extends SuperRemoteInterface implements InvocationHandler {

    final T remoteInterface;


    public static <T> T newInstance(final T obj, RMIClientSocketFactory rcsf, RMIServerSocketFactory rssf) throws RemoteException {
        return (T) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(obj.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                obj.getClass().getInterfaces(), new SecurityInvocationHandler(obj, rcsf, rssf));
    }

    private SecurityInvocationHandler(T remoteInterface, RMIClientSocketFactory csf, RMIServerSocketFactory ssf) throws RemoteException {
        super(csf, ssf);
        this.remoteInterface = remoteInterface;

    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Invoke method -> " + method.getName());
        //TODO
        return method.invoke(remoteInterface, args);   
    }

}
```

SuperRemoteInterface is parent of all classes with Interface "Remote":

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.RMIClientSocketFactory;
import java.rmi.server.RMIServerSocketFactory;

import Config.SysConfiguration;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class SuperRemoteInterface extends UnicastRemoteObject {

    protected SysConfiguration conf;

    protected SuperRemoteInterface() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    protected SuperRemoteInterface(RMIClientSocketFactory clientFactory, RMIServerSocketFactory serverFactory) throws RemoteException {
        super(0, clientFactory, serverFactory);      
    }
}
```

In the main of Server RMI I proxy Object and bind it in rmiregistry:

```
import /****/
public class ServerRMI extends UnicastRemoteObject {

    public ServerRMI() throws RemoteException {
    }

    /*...*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*.....*/

        try {
            //Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);

            RMIClientSocketFactory clientFactory = new RMISSLClientSocketFactory();
            RMIServerSocketFactory serverFactory = new RMISSLServerSocketFactory();

            AInterface proxy = (AInterface)SecurityInvocationHandler.newInstance(new AObject(conf), clientFactory, serverFactory);            



            r.bind("AObject", proxy);
            /* ..... */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Binding it's ok, but in the client side when lookup "AObject", I have this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of $Proxy80 to field java.lang.reflect.Proxy.h of type java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler in instance of $Proxy79
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1212)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1952)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
        at login_web.GetRemoteInterface.getAInterface(GetRemoteInterface.java:35)
        .....
```

Client code is:

```
public class GetRemoteInterface {

    private static final String _port = ":nnnn";
    private String hostAddress;


    public GetRemoteInterface() throws UnknownHostException {
    /*....*/

    public AInterface getAInterface() throws MalformedURLException, RemoteException, NotBoundException{
        return (AInterface) Naming.lookup("//"+hostAddress+_port+"/AObject");
    }


}
```

Without proxy mechanism lookup ok, with these codes not work.
Maybe it isn't possible binding a proxed object with java rmi??

Thanks in advance.

P.S. sorry for my English

Comment: I've done this, so it is certainly possible. But first you need to reconsider your API. It doesn't provide for the case where the remote object implements more than one remote interface. You might find the required redesign illuminating.

Comment: HI @EJP, I read this article [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076234/soa/get-smart-with-proxies-and-rmi.html)`smart-proxy` and then I modify the SecurityInvocationHandler class, with this signature:
 `public class SecurityInvocationHandler<T>  implements InvocationHandler, Serializable {`
and its constructor.
Now, client lookup proxy object, but InvocationHandler run in client-side..

Comment: Of course it does. It's not an exported remote object, so it gets serialized to the client, and executes there. Suppose you take a step back and tell us exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: So, I would implement a security layer, to do login, to retrict method invocation for specific client etc. Yesterday a read this document [A Framework for Smart Proxies and Interceptors in RMI
](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.762&rep=rep1&type=pdf) where it explains what I would do but there are two problems, I quote below:

Comment: "Method marshalling: Another problem that must be addressed is marshalling the method invocation request. When using RMI directly, the stub of the remote object handles this task. **That is lost when the service object stub is replaced by a dynamic proxy**. Therefore, it is necessary to implement a mechanism for forwarding method calls to the server. The ServerProxy is the Remote object used for this purpose. It is general enough so that any method invocation with any number of arguments can be sent through it."

Comment: The dynamic proxy converts the method invocation in two objects that are sent to the invocation
handler: a Method instance describing the method that was invoked, and an object array with the
arguments passed by the client. It is necessary to send this information to the server. The arguments,
which must be Serializable or Remote (otherwise the RMI call would fail anyway), can be sent to
the server directly. But the Method object is not Serializable and therefore cannot be sent directly,
without first being encoded in a Serializable form.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. All you need is the original stub and your own InvocationHandler that wraps the same remote interface. The user calls your proxy, your InvocationHandler runs, it does whatever it's supposed to do locally, it calls the same method on the stub, *voila!*. Nothing else required. I have a product that's been in production since 2001 that does exactly this. The question is, what is it that you're trying to accomplish ... what does your InvocationHandler have to do locally?

Comment: Locally work fine, but I would like InvocationHandler to be executed at server-side no on client-side. InvocationHandler invoke methods on server to check client permission using functions not exposed at client.

Comment: In that case you have to export the proxy before you bind it, with `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject().` This can be non-trivial, as you have to ensure that a dynamic proxy can be constructed from your own dynamic proxy. At a minimum you have to provide a port number, as per the Javadoc preamble for `UnicastRemoteObject,` but if I remember my own product correctly it can get a lot more complex than that.

Comment: Now InvocationHandler run server-side.. but RMI is angry:
`java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
        java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: package.SecurityInvocationHandler
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
        at login_web.GetRemoteInterface.getAInterface(GetRemoteInterface.java:36)...
`

Comment: Please edit your current code into your question. I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: You also need to be aware that the paper you cite is many years out of date and doesn't refer to anything in Java beyond 1.3. Specifically, the dynamic RMI stubs introduced in 1.5 are not even envisaged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you need to export the proxy object itself, not the invocation handler. Otherwise the proxy object gets serialized to the Registry, instead of its stub, with the consequences we see.

So you need to make the following adjustments:

1. `SecureRemoteInvocationHandler` doesn't need to extend `UnicastRemoteObject` either directly or indirectly.
2. You need to add `Remote proxyStub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(proxy, 0, csf, ssf);` before `r.bind()` in `ServerRMI,` where `csf` and `ssf` are the socket factories. (I renamed them in my code.)

There are other improvements you can make:

```
public class SecurityInvocationHandler<T extends Remote>
```

for better type-safety, and similarly:

```
public static <T extends Remote> T newInstance(...)
```

You need to make the variable containing the result of `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` static so it doesn't get garbage-collected.

You need to get adjust all remote object contructors to call `super()` with a port number, so you get dynamic stubs.

You won't get much further than this until you sort out what is required for the SSL handshake to complete. You need to define `javax.net.ssl.keyStore/keyStorePassword` in the server, and `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` in the client if you aren't using the default one (i.e. if the server has a self-signed certificate).

The reason it doesn't work your way is that your exported `SecurityInvocationHandler` replaces itself with its stub during serialization, and that stub isn't an `InvocationHandler,` because `InvocationHandler` isn't a remote interface, so when the object gets deserialized it can't be reassembled, as there is no `InvocationHandler` to store in the dynamic proxy, just this stub, which the dynamic proxy doesn't know from Adam.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, SO limit the comment length, so I write down the missing part in another answer (that exceptions had to been handled by proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for EJP's advice.

I have try this solution, `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject` really helps that proxy code is now run in server side but not client side.

`UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(proxy, 0)` works as expected, I do not have to modify the remote object constructor to call super() because the default super constructor is calling `UnicastRemoteObject(0)`

I have to wrap the invoke call to handle the exception carefully like

```
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, java.lang.reflect.Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return method.invoke(remote, args);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw e.getCause();
    }
}
```

or else client side would got a `java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException` instead of the correct one.